# Redis cluster on load balancer

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cluster

I have setup a redis cluster with 1 master node and 2 slave nodes with sentinel running on all 3 nodes.

Prior to this setup, my application was pointing to a single node where redis instance was running.

After the clustering had been set up, where should my application point to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need more than one master nodes.

Slave is designed not writble

Comment: What would happen when master goes down and one of the slaves are promoted as master?

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the master, and read from both slaves. Of course, you can also read from the master.

In most case, you should NOT write to slave, because even if you config the slave as writable, any write to slave does NOT sync to master or other slaves.

With slave you can achieve data replication. Also, reading from slaves scales out the read performance, if you set up each slave and master on distinct machine. However, you might have consistency problem, i.e. reading inconsistent data from slaves.

Comment: So you are saying, initially I should point my application to the master? What would happen when master goes down and one of the slaves are promoted as master?

Comment: @Ashok Then you should write to the new master. With Redis sentinel you can get the new master's IP and port. Check the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Redis cluster and Redis sentinel are two different concepts. If you only looking for HA I would recommend Sentinel, Redis cluster work on top of sharding which is highly distributed in nature. Redis cluster recommend to have minimum 3 masters and equal quantity of slaves for the healthy cluster.